# getRuntime().freeMemory() available but still VM won't let us allocate 31961088 bytes

Tags: android, memory

I've wrote a function to prevent calling `Bitmap.createBitmap()` if it will throw an `OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`, but I does not always work, how do I correct it? Here is an example where it returns true instead of false:

```
if(isSufficientRAM(width*height)){
    Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    ...
}

public static boolean isSufficientRAM(int length){
    int minRamAfter=1024*1024; //1048576 bytes (always leave at least 1MB free)
    long imgSize=length*4; //this is 31961088 bytes in this case, as it is a 3264 x 2448 argb image
    long freeRAM = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(); //this was 34415992 bytes when I run it   
    boolean hasRAM=freeRAM>imgSize+minRamAfter; //this is true as freeMemory() shows enough RAM available
    return hasRAM;
}
```

When I run this, the function will return true, and Bitmap.createBitmap() gives the error bellow. What am I missing in my isSufficientRAM() function?

```
11-15 09:01:47.965: minRamAfter=1048576
11-15 09:01:47.965: imgSize=31961088
11-15 09:01:47.970: freeRAM=34415992
11-15 09:01:48.020: hasRAM=true
11-15 09:01:48.060: D/dalvikvm(2538): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 79K, 92% free 3850K/44679K, external 2343K/3018K, paused 37ms
11-15 09:01:48.080: E/dalvikvm-heap(2538): 31961088-byte external allocation too large for this process.
11-15 09:01:48.115: E/GraphicsJNI(2538): VM won't let us allocate 31961088 bytes
11-15 09:01:48.115: D/dalvikvm(2538): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 92% free 3850K/44679K, external 2343K/3018K, paused 22ms
11-15 09:01:48.115: W/dalvikvm(2538): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
11-15 09:01:48.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2538): FATAL EXCEPTION: Test thread name
11-15 09:01:48.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2538): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
11-15 09:01:48.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
11-15 09:01:48.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2538):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
```

Comment: If you only have 34MB available, it will rarely contain a [contiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) 31MB block.

Comment: There's also a limitation on memory that can be allocated by an App... see [ActivityManager.getMemoryClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass())

Comment: @Vajk Hermecz: getMemoryClass() returns 64 (MB) so it is not exceeding this one (is a GalaxyS2)

Comment: @Groo "it will rarely contain a contiguous 31MB block" You know this is really true or just presume it? any link/source where you know it from? is very important. For instance i presume heap limitation checks only the total ram used by the app, but not phisicaly allocates a continuous block of ram for that app, so in this case your presumtion will never happen. Thanks

Comment: @user1804542: That's how memory allocation works in Java and C# (honestly, I don't know what Android does in this regards, but I doubt it makes special considerations to consolidate free RAM). Java needs a contiguous block of memory for a single process, yes, but an allocation of an array will also need a contiguous block of memory inside the process memory. It depends on what you're allocating. Lots of small objects will work fine.

Comment: i am allocating a byte[] (a byte array), so i understand i need a continous block of memory inside the memory allocated for my app. How can i get true/false at runtime if this exists or not before i try to allocate it?